# How does the opensea bulk NFT transfer work?

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

I've tried looking at the smart contracts of the bulk transfer function but it confuses me? Like where is the transfer function? If someone could explain it to he that would be appreciated
Here is the code

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000c2d145a2526bD8C716263bFeBe1A72#code

Answer (score 1):

The transfer doesn't actually happen on this contract but from the conduit contract. The sequence goes as follows:

- bulkTransfer calls _performTransfersWithConduit
- then in line 213 conduit's execute function is called

> ```
> try ConduitInterface(conduit).execute(conduitTransfers) returns
> ```

- Conduit then executes the transaction